# How can I use a packaged (exported) stylesheet with saxon 9.7+ s9api?

Tags: java, saxon

Starting with Saxon 9.7 we have to use a different s9api procedure to "import" a packaged stylesheet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37149959/1707353), Michael says "Stylesheet packages can ... be imported ... using ... the s9api API." He then referred to [these](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/compiling) details.

As I read it, hoping that it would be simple, I locked in on this:

> A stylesheet export file ... is accepted by any Saxon interface that accepts a source stylesheet.

So, I created this MCV example:

```
import java.io.*;
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
public class test {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
        Processor saxProc = new Processor(false);
        Configuration saxCfg = saxProc.getUnderlyingConfiguration();
        XsltCompiler saxComp = saxProc.newXsltCompiler();
        File xslmain = new File(args[0]);
        Source xsl = new StreamSource(xslmain);
        XsltExecutable saxExe = saxComp.compile(xsl);
    }
}
```

Executed like this (using 9.9.1.7J for ee, pe, and he) no exception is thrown:

```
$ javac -classpath saxon9pe.jar test.java
$ java -classpath .:saxon9he.jar test something.xsl
```

But if I package up something.xsl (i.e., use EE to export it to an xml file) and execute the MCV like this, then an exception is thrown:

```
$ java -classpath .:saxon9he.jar test something-exported.xml
Error
  SXPK0002: Cannot load expression with tag indexedFilter2. The stylesheet uses Saxon-EE features
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Cannot load expression with tag indexedFilter2. The stylesheet uses Saxon-EE features
```

Shouldn't I be able to package an xsl file using EE, distribute HE, and read the packaged stylesheet using HE to perform transformations? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling it with `-target:HE`. In principle this should stop Saxon-EE generating constructs that the HE run-time won't recognize.

I have to say though, this isn't very thoroughly tested. It may also be necessary to disable selected optimizations using the -opt option.

Comment: If I were able to generate enough tests where my app's XSLT is 100% covered, then I shouldn't expect anything weird, right? In other words, if something is going to fail, would it be an `Exception` either in `XsltCompiler.compile` or `XsltTransformer.transform`? Or is it going to be more subtle (e.g., html is generated from xml but the html is buggy to the point where it can't be detected except for to make a browser render it)?

Comment: I think the most likely failure mode is that you generate a SEF file which Saxon-HE can't load. But bugs are never predictable...